# How to read a percussion note value in C# using the Midi dot net class

Tags: c#, .net, midi

I'm developing a VB.net app which needs to read the MIDI note value from an external drum pad which sends values on channel 10.  This value will be used to control various aspects of my app.

I'm planning on using the MIDI-dot-net class found here: https://code.google.com/p/midi-dot-net/ to read the percussion note value and have looked at one of the examples which reads note played by an external keyboard and displays them.

Unfortunately I can't convert this to do what I want although I think I'm pretty close.

Are there any users out there who are familiar with this library and can spot my error(s) ?  C# isn't my main language (in fact, VB.net isn't either!) but if I can get something running in C# then I can convert it to VB.net for use in my app.

Alternatively, is there another easier way to do what I want ?

Here's my code so far:

```
using System;
using Midi;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MidiExamples
{    
    public class Example05 : ExampleBase
    {
        public Example05()
            : base("Example05.cs", "Prints notes and chords as they are played.")
        { }

        public class Summarizer
        {
            public Summarizer(InputDevice inputDevice)
            {
                this.inputDevice = inputDevice;
                percussionPressed = new Dictionary<Percussion, string>();
                inputDevice.NoteOn += new InputDevice.NoteOnHandler(this.NoteOn);
                inputDevice.NoteOff += new InputDevice.NoteOffHandler(this.NoteOff);
            }

            private void PrintStatus()
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Play notes and chords on the MIDI input device, and watch");
                Console.WriteLine("their names printed here.  Press any QUERTY key to quit.");
                Console.WriteLine();

                // Print the currently pressed notes.
                List<Percussion> percussion = new List<Percussion>(percussionPressed.Keys);
                percussion.Sort();
                Console.Write("Notes: ");
                for (int i = 0; i < percussion.Count; ++i)
                {
                    //Pitch pitch = pitches[i];
                    Percussion percussionNote = percussion[i];
                    if (i > 0)
                    {
                        Console.Write(", ");
                    }
                    Console.Write("{0}", percussionNote.Name());
                }
                Console.WriteLine(); 
            }

            public void NoteOn(NoteOnMessage msg)
            {
                lock (this)
                {
                    percussionPressed[msg.ToString] = true;
                    PrintStatus();
                }
            }

            public void NoteOff(NoteOffMessage msg)
            {
                lock (this)
                {
                    percussionPressed.Remove(msg);
                    PrintStatus();
                }
            }

            private InputDevice inputDevice;
            private Dictionary<Percussion, string> percussionPressed;
        }

        public override void Run()
        {
            // Prompt user to choose an input device (or if there is only one, use that one).
            InputDevice inputDevice = ExampleUtil.ChooseInputDeviceFromConsole();
            if (inputDevice == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No input devices, so can't run this example.");
                ExampleUtil.PressAnyKeyToContinue();
                return;
            }
            inputDevice.Open();
            inputDevice.StartReceiving(null);

            Summarizer summarizer = new Summarizer(inputDevice);
            ExampleUtil.PressAnyKeyToContinue();
            inputDevice.StopReceiving();
            inputDevice.Close();
            inputDevice.RemoveAllEventHandlers();
        }
    }
}
```

Specifically, I'm not sure how to define the NoteOn and NoteOff behaviour ...

Thanks in advance

Phil

Comment: You define the Note On behavior with the [NoteOnMessage](http://midi-dot-net.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Midi/docs/Midi~Midi.NoteOnMessage~Members.html) class.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Robert - that's the bit I'm having trouble with.  Specifically, percussionPressed[msg.ToString] gives me an error about the best overloaded version having missing arguments.  I'm a newb when it comes to both C# and MIDI !  Could you elaborate on how I get the note value ?

Comment: `percussionPressed[msg.ToString]` is array syntax.  More specifically, it refers to an [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6x16t2tx.aspx). Even more specifically, it appears to refer to [this indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb346281.aspx); note that this indexer takes an `int` value as its parameter, not a `string`, and you're trying to pass it a `string`. I'm afraid this is going to be difficult to explain without you having some more background knowledge about how C# works.

Comment: Whoops, my mistake !  OK, I've corrected the definitions so that int's are passed but I can't see how any of the options available for msg in the line percussionPressed[msg.ToString] = true are applicable ?  See here: http://midi-dot-net.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Midi/docs/Midi~Midi.NoteOnMessage~Members.html Only percussionPressed[msg.Pitch] = true appears to be valid (as per the original example) yet that gives the same error about the best overloaded option missing parameters ?

Comment: Where does the `Percussion` object come from?  I see `PercussionMessage` in the library, but not `Percussion`.

Comment: It's here: http://midi-dot-net.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Midi/docs/Midi~Midi.Percussion.html It's an enumeration like Pitch was in the example I copied.  I would have thought that it would be possible to get the note played but there's no Note value, only a Pitch value which doeesn't seem to make sense.  PercussionMessage seems to be an output message rather than an input message.  I've spent hours looking for some sample code to do what I want but no-one seems to have done it and released it :-(

Comment: Have you been able to get any notes out from your code yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would have thought that it would be possible to get the note played but there's no Note value, only a Pitch value which doeesn't seem to make sense.

Unfortunately, this isn't possible.  The pitch value of the note determines what drum sample to play.  The MIDI protocol doesn't specify "snare on" or "timpani on".  It just says C2 or E5.

That being said, if your controller and synth are using General MIDI, there is a map that is usually followed.  [From Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_MIDI#Percussive):

[image]

What I am getting at is that you don't have a code problem.  Your problem is with interpreting those pitch values.

Comment: Thanks Brad, that makes sense.  I just tried the example supplied with MIDI dot Net and I can now see the note values.  It wasn't working before because the USB-MIDI interface had a conflict with another device so it appeared to be installed but wasn't actually working.  Thanks again :-)